# Dimensional modelling few questions

Tags: data-modeling, dimensional-modeling

I am getting familiar with Dimensional model, so started looking at health claims process.  I am trying to acheive the following:

1) ability to report claims by patient by speciality and service provider (monthly, quarterly and yearly)

2) claims by referring provider by service provider

3) claims by monthly payments received for (1) and (2)

4) claims by month of services for (1) and (2)

Here is the dimsion model:

**FactClaims**

Charge Amount

Payment Amount

Service Date Key (FK)

Payment Date Key (FK)

Patient Key (FK)

Service Provider Key (FK)

Facility Key (FK)

Referred Provider Key (FK)

Dimension Tables:

**DimServiceProvider**
ServiceProviderID (SK)

Service Provider Name

Speciality

**DimPatient**
PatientID (SK)

Name

Address

**DimDate**

**DimFacility**
FacilityID (SK, PK)

FacilityName

FacilityRegion

FacilityState

**Questions**:
1) Should i separate fact tables for Charges and Payments?

2) Not sure whether I am thinking correct for Referred Provider Key (which also points to DimServiceProvider)

3) Any rule of thumb to combine some of the dimension tables or separate them?  what are the rules to combine Dimension tables or keep them separate?

Answer (score 0):

Whether separate payments and charges depends on what kind of reports you are going to run. Also, did you consider payments/charges to the insurance, to secondary insurance, if applicable, and to the patient/person responsible for the patient?

If you keep Referred Provider Key, you should provide a special value for self-reffed patients.

There are no dimensions in your model that might be considered for consolidation.

Comment: Good Question, So if I need to capture insurance information, I can probably add a column (DimSourcePaymentKey FK) in the fact table, and add a new Dimension table DimPaymentSource?  Regarding the self referred patients, I can add referredProvider in to DimServiceProvider table and keep the id same for self referred patients?

Comment: Also for the requirements 1-4, should i keep the payments and charges separate or make it one?  There may be one charge per visit, but multiple payments (primary, secondary insurances and personal payments)

Comment: @priceline: In the case of primary insurance/secondary insurance/self pay you might need to capture separate charges. You would bill one or two insurance companies and the patient/responsible party. An insurance company may deny your claim, but the patient would pay his part. You should be able to track that. Or insurance company (ies) would pay, but the patient would be a deadbeat and you would have to sell his debt to a collection agency. Which you also might want to capture in your data warehouse.

Comment: How do i track these changes? Should I add 6 additional fields in the fact table? Like (PrimaryInsuranceCharge, SecondaryInsuranceCharge, SelfPaymentCharge, PrimaryInsurancePayment, SecondaryInsurancePayments, and SelfPayment?  Also TotalCharge and TotalPayment

Comment: @priceline: It really depends on the reports that you are going to run. I kind of hope that the tight relationships between charges and payments related to a service/visit are tracked in your operational data. You need to pull into the warehouse only enough data to do reports. At this stage you might need to interview consumers of your data.